# Recursive: Differences in JSON files not printing as expected

Tags: python, json, recursion, comparison

I am creating code to go through JSON files and print the differences. I created two JSON files with generic data for the sake of sample files to compare.

##### My Code:

```
import json
from recursive_diff import recursive_eq

lhs = json.loads('sample1.json')
rhs = json.loads('sample2.json')

def test1():
    recursive_eq(lhs, rhs)
```

##### Output:

(Personal info redacted.)

```
(env) --$ /Users/--/env/bin/python3.9 /Users/c/Desktop/--/json_compare_recursive.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/--/Desktop/--/json_compare_recursive.py", line 4, in <module>
    lhs = json.loads('sample1.json')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

##### Desired output:

I want it to print explicitly each difference between the two JSON files. For example purposes (actual output would be different):

```
6 differences found

Ln 5, Col 22: , not in lhs
Ln 37, Col 30: "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                    ]
            }, not in lhs
Ln 50, Col 28: 5 not in rhs
```

**Any suggestions on the most efficient way to accomplish this?**

sample1.json code:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }
]
```

sample2.json code:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Raised",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0003",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Old Fashioned",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` Looks like the json file is empty.

Comment: I agree, it does appear that way; however, neither file is empty. I edited my question to include the actual code within each json file.

Comment: I don't get any error loading that sample file.  Are you _sure_ that is the file being used by this code?  Perhaps the code is actually reading another file of the same name in a different directory?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Yes, I am sure this is the file being used as there are no other files with the same name.

Comment: Regardless, I am wanting to find out how to print the desired output in the format I presented above. I will keep looking into the file

Comment: What, exactly, do you want this program to do that is different from running `diff` on the two files?

Comment: I have the "Desired Output" in the question. It may be easier to view that versus re-typing it here.

Comment: The "desired output" finds the first difference on line 5, which is confusing because the two sample files do not differ there as far as i can see.

Comment: @CODSG In your sample code, you use `json.loads` which expects the JSON content as a string, not a filename. You need to use `json.load(open('sample1.json'))` instead.

Comment: @a_guest Good catch!  It's usually something simple like that haha

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, the desired output I presented is for example purposes only and not based on the actual code.

Comment: @a_guest, when I put that, nothing prints out for differences (despite having differences). All that prints is the two file paths

Comment: @CODSG What is `from recursive_diff import recursive_eq`? Where does it come from? Also, please update your question such that it only focuses on the relevant parts. Expected/desired output should match the example given.